# HTML Render with inspect element functionality? HOW TO C#

Tags: c#, html, render, inspect

I want to do a HTML Render that shows a HTML Document, not necessary an online webpage. Then when I click over a HTML Control, it shows only the HTML where I clicked. The real intention is to get the xpath from the root element to the selected TAG.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you must use **System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser** control for loading your html document. Override for example OnLeftButton event of the Form. And then call **WebBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint** method. So this method will return object of **HtmlElement** type. As the result you'll get html element from which you could navigate to inner html source code or navigate by hierarchy of tags from your selected tag;)

I create some example for you:

```
private static String GetTagNameByClick(WebBrowser refWebBrowser, Int32 valScreenX, Int32 valScreenY)
    {
        Point refPoint = refWebBrowser.PointToClient(new Point(valScreenX, valScreenY));

        HtmlElement refHtmlElement = refWebBrowser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(refPoint);

        return refHtmlElement.TagName;
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you edward, it really helped me find the way =) !! now i'm just trying to find out how to get the position clicked on the browser. I tryied your way, but the i had to overload the Document.Click event from the webBrowser.Document to get the event fired. Thank you very much for this light.

Comment: @Johans i did not see your comment! Sorry! As i understand your problem: valScreenX and valScreenY in example are coordinates from the screen, not from Form or WebBrowser control;)

Comment: @Johans use this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx for getting mouse cursor positions "A Point that represents the cursor's position in screen coordinates." ;)