# How do you display HTML in windows app?

Tags: c#, html

I have a bunch of HTML code that I need to display in a label/textbox in a windows app written in c#. It should be in such a way that the output shows the HTML formatted text, rather than the HTML code itself.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Render your HTML in [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control. It has special events for document and you can iterate by tags like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219526/html-render-with-inspect-element-functionality-how-to-c/4221084#4221084) Hope it will help you;)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's a web browser control using IE's rendering engine to display HTML content. You might as well be able to do some simple parsing yourself and use a RTF control but that way you will be rather restricted.

Answer (score 1):

If WebBrowser doesn't suit your needs you can check out these libraries with HTML label/control support

- Telerik Controls for WinForms (Not Free)
  http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx
- GDI+ HTMLRenderer (Free, Open Source)
  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/HtmlRenderer.aspx?msg=2934040

Answer (score 0):

[The HTML Editor](http://www.itwriting.com/htmleditor/index.php) (a wrapper for MSHTML, the rendering portion of Internet Explorer) in read-only mode might be what you need.