# IE's 'Inspect Element' in .NET Webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to use IE's 'Inspect Element' functionality in .NET Webbrowser control ? 
I am using IE 11.

Basically I want to let use select a element same way he does in IE and then on click I want to get back the HTML of that element.

Is it possible to do this using IE's Inspect Element or I have to apply some custom logic ?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Probably not. But have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219526/html-render-with-inspect-element-functionality-how-to-c-sharp

Comment: I am getting elemnet where user has clicked but having problems showing overlay on top of selected element. First it gives me relative position so when my webbrowser control is scrolled , then my dynamically injected overlay is shown on incorrect position... so how can I get absolute positin in scrolled webbrowser control ? Or some builtin mechanism to show overlay on selected element ?

Comment: Not possible. There is no IE web browser console (F12 Developer Tools) for an application hosting `WebBrowser` control. Without some serious custom development, here is as close as you can get to it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18285339/1768303.